# How to get highest quality .tiff from .pdf using linux software?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pdf, image-processing, graphicsmagick

I have very picky label printer and need to convert black and white .pdf file to .tiff image saving as much quality as possible. I have an example .tiff converted using some adobe software and that's the quality I am aiming for.

Tried using graphicsmagick for the job, but I just can't get close enough. Here's a section of an image: on the left side is my try and on the right is the one converted with adobe software:
[image]

As you can see adobe converted image is much thicker but those images are of same resolution (200x400)

Can somebody give me a hint how to convert .pdf to .tiff using most common python libraries or Ubuntu packages and get similar results?

Cheers

Comment: What commands/parameters did you use with GraphicsMagick? And have you got a sample PDF to share? Generally, try setting the density higher before opening your PDF for more quality, e.g.  `convert -density 288 file.pdf file.tif`

Comment: Funny thing - I've tried to remove some sensitive images from the pdf to make you a sample, and all of the sudden quality increased to the desired level. Is it intended that overall .tiff quality is determined according by the lowest quality element? Btw, the command I used is this `convert -density 812 -alpha off in.pdf -scale 400x200 -bordercolor black -border 1x1 -fuzz 20% -trim +repage -colorspace Gray -depth 4 out.tiff`

Comment: Are you just trying to extract the images from your PDF? If so, look at the tool `pdfimages` maybe. Also, by default, ImageMagick applies no compression to TIFFs, so maybe add `-compress LZW` just before your output filename for some lossless compression.

Comment: You could try "-resize 400x200" instead of "-scale 400x200".  According to the ImageMagick documentation, "-scale" is equivalent to using "-resize" with a "-filter" setting of "box". "-scale" is a lot faster, as it avoids all the filter processing of the image.

Comment: Look carefully at the image on the right. Notice that it is not entirely black and white. On the left side of each character there is some red, and on the right side, there is blue. From afar, the image looks pure black and white. The technique of using color to improve quality is called sub-pixel anti-aliasing, which takes advantage of the way LCD screens display text. Adobe uses it to improve quality. The vast majority of libraries do not do this.